# boto3 download with file path

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Can't seem to figure out how to translate what I can do with the cli to boto3 python.

I can run this fine:

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name-format/folder1/folder2/
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name-format/folder1/folder2/myfile.csv.gz
```

Trying to do this with boto3:

```
import boto3
s3  = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1', aws_access_key_id=KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_KEY)


bucket_name = "bucket-name-format"
bucket_dir = "/folder1/folder2/"
bucket = '{0}{1}'.format(bucket_name,bucket_dir)
filename = 'myfile.csv.gz'
s3.download_file(Filename=final_name,Bucket=bucket,Key=filename)
```

I get this error :

*invalid bucket name "bucket-name-format/folder1/folder2/": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}$"*

I know the error is because the bucket name *"bucket-name-format/folder1/folder2/"* is indeed invalid.

Question: how do I add the path? All the examples Ive seen just list the base bucket name

Comment: makes sure your aws cli defaults to the same region.

Comment: cli config says us-east-1,  it matches. I regex checked  "bucket-name-format/folder1/folder2/" and it was invalid

Comment: OH!!! no you need to have the bucket in one string and the full path "prefix" with the file.

s3 is not like a file system the file name is the full path always. the bucket name should not have the path in it.

Comment: ah ok!, I just tried to removed the path in the bucket name and added it to the filename , getting a 403 but I know the file is there.

Comment: 403 means forbidden ;)_

Comment: yah, same creds as cli tho =(

Comment: try not passing the creads if you have a .aws/credentials file with a default profile it should pick that up

Comment: or as environment variables basically just the same as how you pass them to the aws cli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the following command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket-name-format/folder1/folder2/myfile.csv.gz
```

That S3 URI can be broken down into

- Bucket Name: `bucket-name-format`
- Object Prefix: `folder1/folder2/`
- Object Suffix: `myfile.csv.gz`

Really the prefix and suffix are a bit artificial, the object name is really `folder1/folder2/myfile.csv.gz`

This means to download the same object with the boto3 API, you want to call it with something like:

```python
bucket_name = "bucket-name-format"
bucket_dir = "folder1/folder2/"
filename = 'myfile.csv.gz'
s3.download_file(Filename=final_name,Bucket=bucket_name,Key=bucket_dir + filename)
```

Note that the argument to download_file for the Bucket is just the bucket name, and the Key does not start with a forward slash.

Comment: man thats exactly what I needed thanks, I changed `final_name` to`filename` and worked

Comment: How do I add the directory it should be downloaded to? in this syntax, I tried doing , I cant seem to define save path in `download_file` function

Comment: Ah figured it out : `s3.download_file(bucket_name, prefix+filename, 'local_directory/{0}'.format(filename))`